# MVC 4 - Visitor auditing and tracking

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Thought I would put this out there before I embark on my own research.

In a current MVC 4 app, I am looking for a way to track/audit visitors. I am looking for a way to:

1. Record a record on each site request.
2. Record will include things like logged in user, session id, requested page, page coming from, etc., etc.
3. Action methods will be decorated with an attribute to trigger the creation of that record, so we can specify exactly which action methods get logged.

Anyone attempted or heard of anything like this?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: This question isn't very specific... the best I can say is "use ActionFilters" (see [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs), includes information about Logging filters, which is exactly what you want)

Comment: mattytommo - "We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary."

Comment: @Ed, that advice doesn't apply to people with full editing privileges.

Comment: @EdDeGagne especially when the edit does something like putting a numbered list on multiple lines instead of one

Comment: Thanks Jim, that is a great start....

Comment: For the two editors: Kirk, those suggestions apply to everyone, they are not applied differently to individuals with higher capability "badges". Jim, had the original editor waited a little more than the 30 seconds after the post, he would have realized I was in the process of editing it myself. Editing other peoples posts should be about something that adds value, not trivially editing for formatting purposes, especially just moments after the post. That is what looks like self-promotion for earning some other badge.

Comment: Jim, if you want to add your comment as an answer, I will gladly credit you with the answer because unlike the other comments, your comment actually added value to the post and a path to helping me solve my issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ActionFilter seems to be the way to go. I have an example of a similar requirement that I'd be willing to send you, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Derick, but it literally took about 5 minutes to implement this after Jim gave his suggestion (which was the path the original question was on anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider writing a base controller that all your controllers will inherit from and then do all the logging in there.

Comment: Kepha, I do already have a base controller. But that is not a good area for this implementation. I want to have control over WHICH action methods get logged and which ones don't. An ActionFilter is the perfect mechanism for that.